# Verifying a solution exists.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the equation $e^{-x} +2 =x $ has at least one real solution. You may use for this problem the fact that $e^x$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}$

This is asked in an intro to real analysis course and im a bit puzzled but what its asking?

If its asking if it has a root like does there exist an x s.t $e^{-x} +2 -x=0 $ then i guess i could use the fact that x=0 is positive and x=10 it is negative so there must exist by continuity some value of $x \in (0,10) $ s.t $e^{-x} +2 -x=0 $ holds?

Comment: That sounds right. I believe the theorem for this is called the Intermediate Value Theorem

Comment: That's correct, and you're implicitly using here that $e^{-x} + 2 -x$ is continuous to apply Bolzano's theorem.

Comment: Could you link the theorem your talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $$f(x)=e^{-x} +2 -x$$ and its derivatives
$$f'(x)=-e^{-x}-1 \qquad f''(x)=e^{-x}$$ The first derivative is always negative and since $\lim_{x\to -\infty } \, f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty } \, f(x)=-\infty$ then only one root to $f(x)=0$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Use the intermediate value theorem to show the existence of a root. For example, what is the value of $e^{-x}+2-x$ when $x=100$? and $x=-100$?

Comment: Thats not much of a hint i already did that in the posted question for x=0 and x=10 i showed that its negative at x=10 and positive at x=0 so continuity implies that the function is 0 somewhere... but it doesn't seem very analysisie.

Comment: $\ln(1)$ and $\ln(10)$ could be taken to make computation a bit easier.

Comment: @Faust Do you know what the [IVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) is?

Comment: I do but it hasn't been done in class and it was a problem im not supposed to do yet. *facepalm* i was mostly confused by what the question was asking but i understand now i was just being an idiot.

Comment: We know $e^{-x}$ is always decreasing, whereas $x-2$ is always increasing. Thus they have one, and only one real root. How can we prove this?

Comment: thats an interesting question,  im not sure but i would like to know...

Comment: @samjoe further hypotheses are needed.$e^{x}$ is everywhere increasing, and $-e^x$ is everywhere decreasing, so they have at most one solution, but certainly not any. The further hypotheses are essentially equivalent to the  problem at hand: somewhere $x-2<e^{-x}$, and somewhere $e^{-x}<x-2$, which is equivalent to saying less than zero, greater than zero somewhere.

Comment: @Faust I'm sorry the answer was anticlimactic. I'll try to think of something more creative for now, but this certainly seems like the most natural way to proceed.